# When the .then() of deferred method is called?

Tags: angularjs

n $q documentation(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) it is written that "then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. , what result are they talking about ?

Comment: response from the server.

Comment: "Promise" is keyword for Google, here. As Mohammad said, it will resolve then on response from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you resolve your deferred object, the  "then" function is called. For example:

```
function getName(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   setTimeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve("This Name Returned"); // <----- The "then" function is
                                               // called here
   }, 1000);

   return deferred;
}

getName().then(function(name){
  // name = "This Name Returned"
}
```

It doesn't matter if you call deferred.resolve() or deferred.reject(), the "then" will be called. The "then" function accept 2 argument, the first argument is a function that will run when the deferred is resolved, and the second one will be called when the deferred is rejected.